# "gratulieren zu" ohne Dativobjekt

Tags: grammar

In einer etwas längeren Diskussion stellte sich die Frage, ob "gratulieren zu" ohne Dativobjekt funktionieren kann. Konkret ging es um folgende Formulierung.

> Ich gratuliere zu seinem Erfolg.

These 1 ist, dass diese Formulierung nicht funktioniert, weil nicht klar ist, wem gratuliert wird. Die Formulierung

> Ich gratuliere zu deinem Erfolg.

hingegen funktioniert schon, da hier der Adressat implizit gegeben ist.

These 2 ist, dass beide Formulierungen funktionieren. In der ersten Formulierung lässt sich der Adressat genauso gut aus dem Kontext schließen wie in der zweiten. Zudem kann man theoretisch auch einer Drittpartei zu "deinem" Erfolg gratulieren.

> Ich habe deinem Vater zu deinem Erfolg gratuliert.

Die Fragen sind:

- Ist "Ich gratuliere zu seinem [etwas]" grammatisch falsch?
- Ist es stilistisch schlecht/nicht zu verstehen?

Comment: Man kann auch einer "Drittpartei" zu "seinem" Erfolg gratulieren: "Ich habe dem Vater zu seinem(=dem des Sohnes) Erfolg gratuliert." Natürlich muss der Kontext das hergeben. In meinen Augen ist also "Ich gratuliere zu seinem Erfolg" absolut in Ordnung, auch wenn es zum Vater gesagt wird und der Sohn gemeint ist.

Comment: Natürlich muss aus dem Kontext klar sein, worauf sich _seinem_ bezieht, damit der Satz „ich gratuliere zu seinem Erfolg“ funktioniert. Allerdings gilt das nicht nur in diesem Fall, sondern grundsätzlich für den Gebrauch von Pronomen. In der Regel muss die Nominalgruppe, die durch das Pronomen vertreten wird, bereits genannt sein oder als bekannt vorausgesetzt werden können.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vielleicht hilft hier der Grimm weiter. Im Eintrag zu "[gratulieren](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG26475#XGG26475)" liest man:

> **2)** unter ersparung des persönlichen objekts mit bloszer nennung des anlasses, zu dem gratuliert wird, seit dem 18. jh.; im unterschied zu dem gebrauch unter **1** wird dieser anlasz anscheinend fast ausschlieszlich in form einer präpositionalen ergänzung mit zu ausgedrückt:

Es folgen wie immer Zitate, die eine solche Verwendung belegen:

> - zu dem neuen hausgenossen (in Goethes haushalt wurde ein kind erwartet) gratuliere ich im voraus *(1795) Schiller br. 4, 298 Jonas;*
> - ich gratulire zu einer so wünschenswerthen aussicht von thätigkeit *Göthe IV 22, 71 W.;*

Mir ist nicht bekannt, dass diese Verwendung zwischenzeitlich abgeschafft wurde, oder heute als grammatikalisch falsch gesehen wird.

Natürlich kann man einer solchen Aussagen nur den Anlass einer Gratulation entnehmen, nicht aber den Adressaten. Dieser muss sich entweder aus dem Kontext erschließen, oder er ist unwichtig und kann deshalb weggelassen werden.

Weiter unten erwähnen die Grimmms, dass man "gratulieren" sogar auch ganz ohne Objekte verwenden kann:

> **3)** bloszes gratulieren ohne jede nähere bestimmung oder ergänzung, vielfach sogar mit ersparung des personalpronomens, begegnet seit dem ausgehenden 18. jh., nicht selten in militärisch-forscher redeweise:

Auch das geht also sobald sowohl der Anlass als auch der Adressat entweder im Kontext klar sind, oder unwichtig.

Wenn man also die Objekte zu gratulieren weglassen möchte, muss man im weiteren Text darauf achten, dass der Kontext sowohl den Adressaten als auch den Anlass genannt werden, wenn diese zum Verständnid wichtig sind. Das wäre mit einem bloßen Satzschnipsel

> Ich gratuliere zu seinem Erfolg.

noch nicht gegeben. Baut man diesen Satz in einen unmissverständlichen Kontext ein, kann man durchaus sagen:

> Dein Sohn wurde gestern 18. Ich gratuliere zu seinem Geburtstag.

Ob man dies nun stilistisch schön findet oder nicht, sollte jeder für sich selbst entscheiden, meine ich. Jedenfalls haben sich Schiller und Goethe nicht daran gestoßen.